# how to draw several paths on different files in gmplot?

Tags: python

I have several vehicle paths and I would like to automatically draw all of them on separate files. I am trying to do it with a for loop, but the points end up overlapping on each following file. So, basically, on the last file, I have all paths.

This is my function. Can someone help me with this?

```
def drawUnique(uniqueVeh):
    for i in uniqueVeh:
        latitudes = list(map(float,list(gps_data[gps_data["id"] == i]["lat"])))
        longitudes = list(map(float,list(gps_data[gps_data["id"] == i]["long"])))
        gmap.scatter(latitudes, longitudes, size=10, marker=False)
        gmap.draw("map" + i + ".html")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the declaration of the `gmap` object, that is made obviously before the loop, so the same object is used and saves all the marks.

You just need to define a new `gmap` object at the beginning of each iteration to create a fresh new map:

```
def drawUnique(uniqueVeh):
    for i in uniqueVeh:
        gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(center_lat, center_lng, zoom) # replace the values !!

        latitudes = list(map(float,list(gps_data[gps_data["id"] == i]["lat"])))
        longitudes = list(map(float,list(gps_data[gps_data["id"] == i]["long"])))
        gmap.scatter(latitudes, longitudes, size=10, marker=False)
        gmap.draw("map" + i + ".html")
```

---

Basically the code in the question can be converted like below:

```
import gmplot
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(40.640, -73.926, 16)    

# turn 1
gmap.scatter([40.642810, 40.638240], 
             [-73.915, -73.922901], 
             'cornflowerblue', edge_width=8)
gmap.draw("map1.html")

# turn 2 
# same gmap : all marks are added and overlap the first
gmap.scatter([40.644494, 40.637083], 
             [-73.925044, -73.926464], 
             'red', edge_width=8)
gmap.draw("map2.html")
```

You need to insert this line between each drawing to avoid the overlapping issue in `map2.html` :

```
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(40.640, -73.926, 16)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked! If I want to change the color of each point depending on the speed, how should I do it?  I tried using color = speed (where speed is another column in my gps_data), but it didn't work. I also tried color = ["r", "b"...], it also didn't work.

Comment: You can create a function to map the speed values to a named color, with something like `if 0<speed<50: return 'red'` but this could be another good question to ask here.

Comment: Is there a way to plot multiple polygons on one graph with gmplot?